# What is the maximum number of edges in a planar bipartite graph that has n vertices from each side?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

What is the maximum number of edges in a planar bipartite graph of order 2n that has n vertices from each side?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098587/maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-bipartite-graph) may be of some use.

Comment: Its not, because its not planar over there. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In every planar graph we have (Euler's formula):

$$V - E + F = 2$$

Where $V$, $E$, $F$ is the number of vertices, edges and faces respectively. Since the bipartite graph has no odd length cycles, the smallest cycle (and thus face) has $4$ edges. The sum of numbers of edges of each face equals twice the number of edges, so:

$$4F \le 2E$$

Which in conclusion with previous equality yields:

$$E \le 2V - 4$$

And in case of a bipartite graph having $n$ vertices on each side we have:

$$E \le 4n - 4$$

This can be achieved by an easy construction - picture $n$ vertices in a row numbered $1a$, $2a$, ... $na$ from one set and the other (call them $1b$, $2b$, ..., $nb$) directly below them (like in the grid). Then connect $1a$ to $1b$, $2a$ to $2b$ and so on with straight lines ($n$ edges), then connect $1b$ to $2a$, $2b$ to $3a$ and so on, again with straight lines ($n - 1$ edges) creating a "zigzag" pattern. Finally, connect $1a$ to all vertices on the other side by curved edges over of the grid ($n - 1$ edges because $1a$ and $1b$ are already connected) and connect $nb$ to all vertices on the other side by curved edges under the grid ($n - 2$ edges because $nb$ is already connected with $na$ and $1a$).

Comment: What is the construction? I tried to find it but couldn't please see my other question...

Comment: @dave I've edited my answer and provided details on the construction.

Comment: You also wrote in your proof "no even length cycles", you meant odd right?

Comment: @dave Yes, edited again.

Comment: Thanks, reading it now.

Comment: It hold only for n>=2 right?

Comment: @dave yes, for $n = 1$ we can achieve more than $0$ edges by connecting the only two vertices with $1$ edge. That is because our only "face" in this case is quite strange.

Comment: There is a mistake I believe at the end of your construction: you meant that nb is connected to 1a and na. Isn't it?

Comment: @dave Indeed - corrected.